# check if transaction is spendable in bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj

Is there some kind of check if incoming transaction is normally spendable by the bitcoinj wallet? I mean to check if there is no time lock and it's not multisig or whatever can prevent receiver from spending such transaction ? I'm interested in solution within bitcoinj library, online tool might be usefull too.